# Raid filesystem check or mount failed (after probable physical shock)

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mount, fstab

I was redirected here from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178077/raid-filesystem-check-or-mount-failed-after-probable-physical-shock).

I work on a server where the operating system is installed on an SSD but data storage is on internal harddrives set up in a RAID system. Recently I have been unable to mount the raid system when booting, while the operating system loads fine. I suspect technicians hit the server while it was running, due to scratches on the case but I am not sure.

When I boot the computer I get the error message `The drive for /home is not ready or present` (the same message for `/Data` and `/Backup`.  I entered the recovery shell and ran `fsck -A` as suggested in the post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524574/filesystem-check-or-mount-failed), but I get the message that `/` was busy.

I then booted into recovery mode and ran `fsck -A`, but I get the message that

```
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=334eef34-16c4-45ec-9cc9-5f40e9f8207d'
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=19bf1002-fa4b-4462-9ea6-807d5b0f312b'
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=0f556fa7-b061-4c22-b84b-97e2e3f1b545'
```

At [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=859779) I found the suggestion to edit `/etc/fstab` but I am out of my depth here as I do not really understand what I am messing with.

running `blkid` returns

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="7c05724f-61bd-4d70-b908-f6c83c4365b8" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="51978b9f-747b-4f41-8b2b-42f3da3347e6" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="13151e15-3890-90d5-d910-8ab781fc713f" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="05322b31-8961-f57d-143b-877123c61d7c" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="85430436-4dfc-96ff-083c-0734a76ff8b6" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sde1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="05feb9dd-9c4f-bc2f-50e7-c4422419268a" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdf1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="3ef48a37-14b5-1fc8-1eed-48eca24f0043" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="65325870-b912-f8b1-af82-ab0c8bb94dbb" UUID_SUB="5960eff8-d60b-c206-90b9-c448723f9ef3" LABEL="CBMRubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
```

and running `cat /etc/fstab` prints

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7c05724f-61bd-4d70-b908-f6c83c4365b8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /Backup was on /dev/md0p2 during installation
UUID=334eef34-16c4-45ec-9cc9-5f40e9f8207d /Backup         ext4    defaults        0       2
# /Data was on /dev/md0p1 during installation
UUID=19bf1002-fa4b-4462-9ea6-807d5b0f312b /Data           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/md0p3 during installation
UUID=0f556fa7-b061-4c22-b84b-97e2e3f1b545 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=51978b9f-747b-4f41-8b2b-42f3da3347e6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I noticed that the missing UUIDs are the same as the ones in `/etc/fstab/` but does not match the ones in `blkid`. Is there some way to figure out which UUIDs goes where and restore the file system?

The vast majority is backed up so the damage is not great, but there are a few things that would be nice to restore.

I work on a server with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, if that makes a difference.

---

The output of `lsblk` is

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
|-sda1   8:1    0  95.6G  0 part /
|-sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
`-sda5   8:5    0   128G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
`-sdb1   8:17   0   3.7T  0 part
sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk
`-sdc1   8:33   0   3.7T  0 part
sdd      8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk
`-sdd1   8:49   0   3.7T  0 part
sde      8:64   0   3.7T  0 disk
`-sde1   8:65   0   3.7T  0 part
sdf      8:80   0   3.7T  0 disk
`-sdf1   8:81   0   3.7T  0 part
sdg      8:96   0   3.7T  0 disk
`-sdg1   8:97   0   3.7T  0 part
```

and the output of `mdadm -E /dev/sd*` is:

```
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :    200531968 sectors at         2048 (type 83)
Partition[1] :    268324866 sectors at    200536062 (type 05)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda1.
/dev/sda2:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :    268324864 sectors at            2 (type 82)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda5.
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 65325870:b912f8b1:af82ab0c:8bb94dbb
           Name : CBMRubuntu:0  (local to host CBMRubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed May  7 09:29:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 19534425600 (18629.48 GiB 20003.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 13151e15:389090d5:d9108ab7:81fc713f

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:48:15 2019
       Checksum : ba5f0a8c - correct
         Events : 2164

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 65325870:b912f8b1:af82ab0c:8bb94dbb
           Name : CBMRubuntu:0  (local to host CBMRubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed May  7 09:29:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 19534425600 (18629.48 GiB 20003.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 05322b31:8961f57d:143b8771:23c61d7c

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:42:49 2019
       Checksum : 757ceca0 - correct
         Events : 2046

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 65325870:b912f8b1:af82ab0c:8bb94dbb
           Name : CBMRubuntu:0  (local to host CBMRubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed May  7 09:29:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 19534425600 (18629.48 GiB 20003.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 85430436:4dfc96ff:083c0734:a76ff8b6

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:48:15 2019
       Checksum : f94f436a - correct
         Events : 2164

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : A.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sde:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 65325870:b912f8b1:af82ab0c:8bb94dbb
           Name : CBMRubuntu:0  (local to host CBMRubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed May  7 09:29:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 19534425600 (18629.48 GiB 20003.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 05feb9dd:9c4fbc2f:50e7c442:2419268a

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:48:15 2019
       Checksum : b315a5ff - correct
         Events : 2164

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : A.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdf:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 65325870:b912f8b1:af82ab0c:8bb94dbb
           Name : CBMRubuntu:0  (local to host CBMRubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed May  7 09:29:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 19534425600 (18629.48 GiB 20003.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 3ef48a37:14b51fc8:1eed48ec:a24f0043

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:48:15 2019
       Checksum : 7a83dfe - correct
         Events : 2164

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : A.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdg:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 65325870:b912f8b1:af82ab0c:8bb94dbb
           Name : CBMRubuntu:0  (local to host CBMRubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed May  7 09:29:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813771264 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 19534425600 (18629.48 GiB 20003.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 5960eff8:d60bc206:90b9c448:723f9ef3

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:48:15 2019
       Checksum : 14c8bd1e - correct
         Events : 2164

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : A.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Comment: Sorry, but with that outdated version of Ubuntu your question is here just as off topic as on askubuntu.

Comment: I see... even though it is a problem that is fundamentally not related to the version I am using? Do you have a suggestion for where I could ask this question?
If I update ubuntu to a newer version will this question then become on-topic?

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to update it, so the question is moot. A hin I can give you is that the comments regarding `/home was on /dev/md0p3 during installation` indicates that your physical discs were configured in a software raid. The tools from the `mdadm` package could be helpful diagnosing and resolving the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will see if that can get me started

Comment: It is quite possible that you wrecked the filesystem on the raid by running fsck directly on the disks instead of the raid device.

Comment: I have not run fsck on anything except the SSD with where ubuntu is installed. Any attempt to run it on the disks failed before they could run, so I am hopeful that is not the case.

Comment: I'm not so fazed about the (slightly) out-of-support Ubuntu version, but an answer to this question is extremely hard to formulate because there isn't enough info, and I'm worried that given your apparent lack of experience with the system configuration, extracting the necessary information would require a lengthy discussion.  At the very least, though, the output of `lsblk` and `mdadm -E /dev/sd*` *may* provide sufficient information to give an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you womble. I have updated the question with the output of the commands. I appreciate that you don't want to waste time, so I hope that this is quick to solve, otherwise I will try to solve it on my own or accept the loss and buy new harddrives.